# Python import pygame does not play an audio

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, mp3

the code just print the name of the song and dont stop after he finish
my code:

```
import glob
import os

os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = "hide"

import pygame

songs = glob.glob("C:\\Users\zivsi\Music\\*.mp3")
import random

song = random.choice(songs)
song_name = song.replace("C:\\Users\zivsi\Music\\", "").replace(".mp3", "")
print("song: ", song_name)

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

I did not use from pygame import * 
because it cannot be done in def

Comment: I don't understand if the problem is that the music doesn't start or if it never stops

Answer (score 0):

Use `pygame.mixer.music.stop()` when you want to stop the music. The `pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)` computes the time since it was last called and stalls the program until 1/framerate (in your case framerate=10) seconds have passed. Therefore, your code will run until the song is done playing. If instead you want to pause the program for a set amount of time and stop the music from playing, use `time.sleep()`, which takes seconds as an argument. Possible example:

```
import glob
import os
import time

os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = "hide"

import pygame

songs = glob.glob("C:\\Users\zivsi\Music\\*.mp3")
import random

song = random.choice(songs)
song_name = song.replace("C:\\Users\zivsi\Music\\", "").replace(".mp3", "")
print("song: ", song_name)

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

time.sleep(10) #sleep for 10 seconds before moving on
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you. i understand now. my mistake was:
    pygame.init()  - 
i need
pygame.mixer.init()